# Springboot application throws a NoSuchBeanDefinitionException trying to Autowire CouchbaseCluster

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, couchbase, autowired

I work with a legacy springboot application which has a huge com.mycompany.MyApplication class where there are injected a bunch of spring objects through @Autowire annotation.
Trying to split MyApplication class up, I created several classes and put them in different packages but I got an issue with **CouchbaseCluster** autowire injection; the error is:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'step'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jobSteps': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'couchbaseFlushCacheTasklet'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'couchbaseFlushCacheTasklet': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cluster'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field cluster in com.mycompany.batch.tasklet.CouchbaseFlushCacheTasklet required a bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseCluster' in your configuration.
```

Here is an example of my code:

```
package com.mycompany;

@EnableBatchProcessing
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    JobSteps step;

    ...
}
```

```
package com.mycompany.batch;

@Configuration
public class JobSteps {

    @Autowired
    CouchbaseFlushCacheTasklet couchbaseFlushCacheTasklet;

    @Autowired
    CouchbaseDeleteNonBatchTasklet couchbaseDeleteNonBatchTasklet;

    ...

}
```

If you note in the next code snipped, cluster uses the @SuppressWarnings annotation because **Intellij** marks this with this error: '`Could not autowire. No beans of 'CouchbaseCluster' type found.'` however it was before and after my changes, but before the application ran without issues.

```
package com.mycompany.batch.tasklet;

@Component
public class CouchbaseFlushCacheTasklet {

    @SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaInjectionPointsAutowiringInspection")
    @Autowired
    CouchbaseCluster cluster;

    ...
}
```

I am putting this next class to show that there is any problem with the bean Budget, which is located in the same library/package than CouchbaseCluster `com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket`

```
package com.mycompany.batch.tasklet;

@Component
public class CouchbaseDeleteNonBatchTasklet {

    @Autowired
    Bucket bucket;

    ...
}
```

POM dependencies associated with couchbase

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried to specify the scanBasePackeges but didn't work.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.mycompany", "com.couchbase.client"})
```

Any clue will be appreciated since I have spent a lot of time looking for a solution and so far none of the suggested things in similar posts have worked.

I solved it :-)
Instead of autowire this

```
    @Autowired
    CouchbaseCluster cluster;
```

I autowire this

```
    @Autowired
    Cluster cluster;
```

I am not sure how was possible that at some point it worked autowiring `CouchbaseCluster`

Answer (score 0):

First thing `CouchbaseCluster class` should be part of the bean life cycle, it should be annotated with an annotation like @Component etc. if so you must check you should not be creating the object of any class using the `new` keyword.
So in your case, it will be resolved something like this. add the below method into `JobSteps`.

```
@Bean 
public CouchbaseCluster couchbaseCluster(){

 CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
            .bootstrapCarrierDirectPort(couchbase.getMappedPort(11210))
            .bootstrapCarrierSslPort(couchbase.getMappedPort(11207))
            .bootstrapHttpDirectPort(couchbase.getMappedPort(8091))
            .bootstrapHttpSslPort(couchbase.getMappedPort(18091))
            .build();
    CouchbaseCluster cc = CouchbaseCluster.create(env);

    return cc;

    }
```

Modified the `CouchbaseEnvironment` object according to your configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating your Cluster in the @PostConstruct?

```
@Service
public class CouchbaseFlushCacheTasklet {
    private Cluster cluster;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.create();
        cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "localhost");
    }
...
}
```

Code from: https://www.baeldung.com/couchbase-sdk-spring

Alternatively, try adding an @Bean producer somewhere instead of using a @PostConstruct.

Comment: Thank you @Tom, I just tried it but got the exactly same error.